# Ext.window.Window minimum button is not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4

On my extjs4 view I set the minimizable to true but after click on the min button the view is not minimized.  The maximum button is working.  Do I need to set other property for the window to make it work?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation, so I'll just quote it here:

> True to display the 'minimize' tool button and allow the user to
>   minimize the window, false to hide the button and disallow minimizing
>   the window. Note that this button provides no implementation -- the
>   behavior of minimizing a window is implementation-specific, so the
>   minimize event must be handled and a custom minimize behavior
>   implemented for this option to be useful.